# triangulo de pascal c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, net

No se si alguien me podría orientar me dejaron hacer un árbol de este tipo

```
           1
          212
         32123
        4321234
```

solo que al momento de jalarlo en consola no me aparece de la manera de arriba si no en lineal todo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Lo hice con for para facilitarme un poco mas, pero igual al jalarlo asi y darle enter me saca de la consola de igual manera.

```
namespace PiramideAsteriscos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("inserta en número el nivel de la pirámide, mayor a cero");
 
            int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " \t ");
                //primera parte
                for (int j = 1; j <= (N - i) + 1; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("* ");
                }
                //segunda parte
                int numeroFila = i;
                Boolean bandera = true;
                for (int j = 1; j <= (i * 2) - 1; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(numeroFila + " ");
                    if (bandera)
                    {
                        numeroFila--;
                        if (numeroFila == 1)
                        {
                            bandera = false;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    numeroFila++;
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    numeroFila ++;
                    //}
                }
                for (int j = 1; j <= (N - i) + 1; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("* ");
                }

                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El triángulo de pascal no es así. ¿Seguro que es eso lo que quieres hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Dejo código con explicación en comentarios:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++){
            WriteLevel(i, n);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
    public static void WriteLevel(int level, int maxLevel){
        
        // Escribir los espacios de relleno a la izquierda
        Console.Write("".PadLeft(maxLevel - level, ' '));
        
        // Escribir la secuencia de números desde i = level hasta i = ( 0 - level)
        // Se usa Abs() para quitar los números negativos
        // Si i es cero o i es -1 se ignora la iteración
        // porque la secuencia no lleva 0 ni el 1 duplicado
        for(int i = level; i >= (0 - level); i--){
            if(i == 0 || i == -1) continue;
            Console.Write(Math.Abs(i));
        }
        
        // Escribir los espacios de relleno a la derecha
        Console.Write("".PadRight(maxLevel - level, ' '));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa LinQ:

1. Genera una secuencia de números ascendente desde `2` a un valor determinado.

   ```
   var linea = Enumerable.Range(2, altura).Select(a => a.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b)
   ```
2. Genera su versión reversa

   ```
   var reverse = new String(linea.Reverse().ToArray());
   ```
3. Escribe la secuencia reversa junto a la no reversa poniendo un `1` entre ellas, añade espacios para centrar.

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(altura_max - altura - 1, ' ') + reverse + "1" + linea);
   ```

Todo junto quedaría así:

```
int altura_max = 9;
for (int altura = 0; altura != altura_max; ++altura)
{
    if (altura > 0)
    {
        var linea = Enumerable.Range(2, altura).Select(a => a.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
        var reverse = new String(linea.Reverse().ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(altura_max - altura - 1, ' ') + reverse + "1" + linea);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(altura_max - altura - 1, ' ') + "1");
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVDNasJAED4nTzH14i7RxfZWgoIUbxZECz2UUsY4hoVkt51dbaX47OmYaOsD9DLMfPP9DFOEYeGZmmYXrCthdQiR6jy9nszcuo88TYsKQ4AF@5KxTr/TJESMtoC9txt4ROtUiCyyl1dALoNOE@Ek1kXAKu4Y32r8gjHc54JuPYP6Wwk8yi/9zfhKkEOWdZP4tYaJ3YI6UycwOsEdnuyRobKOTnYzt6uJcV2RWaIrSd0Nzq7arKiiIiqhTQDNk1@1ZyutzbQsmUqMpBQOYK1bBmTS5b8JTHviQJLh6BPO2jbWLLuV0mI6ZcaDeHbCB@@Cl1ue2UaSf5LqhGZWv8eDWeBmTtuorh41vLxjCLcD6ENfyx2X7Ax6tz2pbWwXcTwVqgL9Z56ktO5ifkyPTfMD)</kbd>.